# Batch file on Macos to execute lynx command to download a list of websites

Tags: python, macos, command

I am trying to prepare a qualitative dataset for a research. I have a big list of websites that I classified for certain topics. What I need is not complicated but exceeds my knowledge of command line.
I need to use lynx command line tool to dump various websites to .txt file. such as: lynx -dump -nolist "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey" > file.txt
I have a list of 1000 websites, so it is virtually impossible to do it one by one.
How can I create a script on mac osx to get the list from a text file for instance and dump all the content to one single text file. If it is impossible to do it on one text file, how do I do it by creating a new file respectively to follow each other. Files names per-se can be file(1), file(2) or so.. But anyways, one single dump file would be way better.
Is that possible? Or can this be done by simple programming?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a `bash` one-liner like this:

```
while read l; do echo "##########"; echo $l; echo "##########"; lynx -dump -nolist "$l"; done < sites.txt > results.txt
```

That assumes your list is in a file called `sites.txt` and you want the results in a file called `results.txt`.

---

Alternatively, if you use **homebrew**, you can install **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
brew install parallel
```

and then get the job done much quicker with:

```
parallel -j 16 -a sites.txt lynx -dump -nolist > results.txt
```